# Error: The non-abstract class is missing implementations for these members: HttpClientRequest.abort

Tags: flutter, dart

After updating Flutter to the **master** channel, previously compiling code pieces started to fail building with the following error:

```
../pub.dartlang.org/testfairy-1.x.y/lib/src/network_logging.dart:253:7: 
            Error: The non-abstract class '_TestFairyClientHttpRequest' is missing implementations for these members:
     - HttpClientRequest.abort
    Try to either
     - provide an implementation,
     - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
     - mark the class as abstract, or
     - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
    class _TestFairyClientHttpRequest implements HttpClientRequest {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:2045:8: Context: 'HttpClientRequest.abort' is defined here.
      void abort([Object? exception, StackTrace? stackTrace]);
           ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the new installation now has dependency to unreleased code, some classes in Dart and Flutter SDK may now have new methods added to them which may be experimenting with new APIs. The solution is locating each missing/erroneous method and fixing their signature by locating their ancestors in the [Flutter's](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) or [Dart's](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk) repos, using master branches.

For the specific case in the question, the solution was adding the following implementation to the malfunctioning class, referenced from the [base implementation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart#L2045):

```
@Since("2.10")
@override
void abort([Object? exception, StackTrace? stackTrace]) {
    // your implementation
}
```

Comment: I have a blog post, explaining my specific problem more in depth: https://testfairy.com/blog/developing-with-flutter-master-channel/